# Preencimento de campo, com referência no campo anterior

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Comecei a aprender sobre python de django e estou tentando desenvolver um sistema simples de gestão de veiculos. Estou batendo cabeça pra realizar o seguinte procedimento: assim que for digitado a placa do veiculo cadastro ele me retornar no campo `medida_de_saida` o valor do hodômetro cadastrado no veiculo.

[image: 1]

```
from django.db import models
from veiculos.models import Veiculos
from motoristas.models import Motoristas
from veic_dados.models import Secretarias


class Retirada(models.Model):
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    motorista = models.ForeignKey(Motoristas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secretaria = models.ForeignKey(Secretarias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_retirada = models.DateTimeField()
    ultima_medida = queryset = Veiculos.objects.all().only('medida_inicial')
    medida_de_saida = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    destino = models.TextField()
    passageiros = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.veiculo


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UAA.png
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso **medida_de_saida** sempre será um valor fixo e você nunca irá editar?

Se esse for o caso você pode usar um Sobrescrever o metodo save() do django.

```
class Retirada(models.Model):
veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
motorista = models.ForeignKey(Motoristas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
secretaria = models.ForeignKey(Secretarias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_retirada = models.DateTimeField()
ultima_medida = queryset = Veiculos.objects.all().only('medida_inicial')
medida_de_saida = models.CharField(max_length=6, editable=False)
destino = models.TextField()
passageiros = models.TextField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.medida_de_saida = 'LOGICA PARA CALCULAR ULTIMA MEDIDA AQUI'
    super(Retirada, self).save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.veiculo
```

Veja se deu para entender, e se eu entendi corretamente sua dúvida!

Comment: Exato na 'ultima_medida' sempre sera um valor fixo que esta cadastrado em 'veiculo' quando a placa for digitada ele apresenta a km final desse veículo. Essa 'LOGICA PARA CALCULAR ULTIMA MEDIDA AQUI' o que seria?

Comment: Aonde eu inseri a 'LÓGICA .... ' é só você colocar a logica para calcular isso. Esse campo não será editável e toda vez que você salvar o modelo automaticamente e vai realizar sua logica e salvar isso no banco, e você consegue acessar normalmente. Veja se consegue, e estou aqui para tentar ajudar!

Comment: Fiz uma correção, o certo é **self.medida_de_saida**, por exemplo se a medida de saida for sempre a ultima medida multiplicado por dois. Aquela linha ficaria **self.medida_de_saida = self.ultima_medida * 2** ! Não consegui complementar mais, pois não conheço nada da regra de negocio.

Comment: **self.medida_de_saida = Veiculos.objects.get(id=self.veiculo_id).hodometro_valor**

Ia ficar mais ou menos assim, eu não sei como está estruturada sua outra tabela no banco.

Comment: O seu self está instanciado errado, o medida saída irá receber um valor e o editable dele deve ser false na declaração do campo. O resto parece estar certo se esse é o dado que você quer acessar de outra tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei dessa forma, mais o campo ultima_medida, continua não aparecendo.

```
from django.db import models
from veiculos.models import Veiculos
from motoristas.models import Motoristas
from veic_dados.models import Secretarias


class Retirada(models.Model):
veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
motorista = models.ForeignKey(Motoristas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
secretaria = models.ForeignKey(Secretarias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_retirada = models.DateTimeField()
ultima_medida = queryset = Veiculos.objects.filter().only('medida_inicial')
medida_de_saida = models.CharField(max_length=6)
destino = models.TextField()
passageiros = models.TextField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ultima_medida = Veiculos.objects.get(id=self.veiculo).medida_inicial
    super(Retirada, self).save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.veiculo
```

Answer (score 0):

Mudei o código e o campo 'ultima_medida' apareceu, mais não aparece a ultima medida relatava ao veiculo selecionado. Em vez disso aparece as mesmas informaçoes do campo 'veiculo'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from django.db import models
from veiculos.models import Veiculos
from motoristas.models import Motoristas
from veic_dados.models import Secretarias


class Retirada(models.Model):
veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
motorista = models.ForeignKey(Motoristas, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
secretaria = models.ForeignKey(Secretarias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_retirada = models.DateTimeField()
ultima_medida = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Ultima_Medida')
medida_de_saida = models.CharField(max_length=6)
destino = models.TextField()
passageiros = models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.veiculo


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ultima_medida = Veiculos.objects.get(id=self.veiculo).medida_inicial
    super(Retirada, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

O django possui "despachante de sinais" ([signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/))
Alguns sinais disponibilizados:

- django.db.models.signals.pre_delete
- django.db.models.signals.post_delete
- django.db.models.signals.pre_save
- django.db.models.signals.post_save

Para ter acesso a algum valor antes de novo valor ser salvo na base de dados,
pode-se utilizar o django.db.models.signals.pre_save, com 
assinatura: receiver(sender, instance, raw, using, update_fields)
O campo instance está com os dados atualizados. Mas, como ainda não foi salvo no
banco de bados, qualquer consulta de recuperação que fizer, tipo:
`Retirada.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)` 
retornará os dados não atualizados.

Excelente artigo para te ajudar: [How to Create Django Signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html)